# How to create this shape in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to create this shape in the latest version of Illustrator CC:

[image: shape]

I tried the pen tool but wasn't sure if that was the right approach since this is geometrical.

Comment: How is the Pen tool unable to draw geometric figures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I'd use the pen tool, with the aid of some guides. There are undoubtedly several ways you could approach such a design. Here's one method.

Make guides on the original where each of the corner nodes should fall, and use these to draw the basic shapes and curves. Make the strokes thick.

Reflect copies of the basic shapes over to the other side. Switch on Smart Guides to make sure the positioning is exact. Draw the top arch using the pen tool, making sure the curves on each side are the same. In the example below you can see me select each basic shape, and it's reflected copy on the other side.

[image]

When you've finished, you could expand the lines, and combine them using the pathfinder Union, and draw the little shadows using the pen tool, and use pathfinder Divide, and delete the parts you don't want.

[image]

The finished graphic

[image]

Comment: Yes this also is an answer. Bro How do you do the animation of this. is better than screenshot?

Comment: @DodieEslava I use ShareX to create gif screen captures.